# Discord.py: how to wait for user reaction to the BOT comment?

Tags: discord.py

I want to make a BOT that do something depending on  the user reaction on the BOT post. Somethign like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz0dZ.jpg, but not for voting only to know if the user is sure to execute the command, hope I'm clear. Thank you for any reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `client.on_reaction_add(reaction, user)` [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add)

Answer (score 4):

In the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for) you will see a function `wait_for()`. This can be used to wait for a certain event. Such as a message or reaction add. In this case you want to wait for a reaction add.

In the second example of the documentation is explained how you can use it:

```
reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
```